# How can I update Username and password in aspnet_Users table and other table was created by me tbl_users simultaneously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am Making a Web project and maintaining role management in this application. When I had been created web project then I defined role management in this application. When I create an user using `createUser()` function data stores in `aspnet_Users`,`aspnet_Membership` and other table that one has been created by me `(tbl_users)`,stores all user information including some info of `aspnet_Users`,`aspnet_Membership` table. I am able to create data in these tables  simultaneously but now I want to update and delete data in these tables  simultaneously,how can it be possible please??..let me know.

Here is My code

```
protected void btn_signup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                // Create new user.
            objuser.email=txt_email.Text;
            objuser.password=txt_password.Text;
            objuser.username = TextBox1.Text;
            if (Membership.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer)
            {
                MembershipUser newUser =
                Membership.CreateUser(objuser.email,objuser.password,
                                         objuser.username);
            }
            else
            {
                MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(
                 objuser.email,
                 objuser.password,
                 objuser.username);
                int i = BusinessUser.BusinessRegisterUser(objuser);
                 if (i > 0)
                 {
                     Session["user_authenticate"] = "Verified";
                     Session["user_email"] = objuser.email;
                     Label1.Text = Session["user_email"].ToString();
                     login1.Style.Add("display", "none");
                     logout.Visible = true;
                     Response.Redirect("user_registration.aspx");

                 }

            }
            show_menu();
            //Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException ex)
        {
            WarningModal.Show();
           lblWarning.Text = GetErrorMessage(ex.StatusCode);
           pnlIssues.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (HttpException ex)
        {
            WarningModal.Show();
            lblWarning.Text= ex.Message;

        }
    }


  protected void loginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
           {

           if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginUser.UserName, loginUser.Password))
                {
                    Session["user_authenticate"] = "Verified";
                    e.Authenticated = true;
                    Session["user_email"] = loginUser.UserName;
                    objuser.email = Session["user_email"].ToString();
                    Label1.Text = Session["user_email"].ToString();
                    login1.Style.Add("display", "none");
                    logout.Visible = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    e.Authenticated = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to update aspnet_user table and aspnet_membership table and tbl_user table simultaneously plz help me

Comment: You could look at creating a custom membership provider which updates the aspnet membership and your custom membership

Answer (score 0):

You could always put a trigger on the aspnet_membership table that cascades the update and delete actions to the tbl_user table.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx